Simple Direct Proof of Nakayama's Lemma
Is there a simple direct proof of (this version of) Nakayama's Lemma? By simplicity, I am mostly referring to the concepts required to understand the proof, not how terse the proof is. I have no doubt that the proof in the book is correct, but it is hard to digest for someone like me with a weak understanding of ring theory.

I'm interested in the statement of Nakayama's Lemma on page 65 of Noncommutative Algebra by Dennis and Farb. I know there are other versions of the lemma floating around out there (in particular the one in Atiyah-Macdonald is different), but I like this one.

Lemma 2.1.1 (Nakayama's Lemma): If $M$ is a finitely generated $R$-module such that $J(R)M = M$, then $M = 0$.

The proof in the book appears to be a proof by contradiction (although my understanding of it is weak and it may not use contradiction in an essential way) and I find it somewhat difficult to understand. I don't really understand how it is using the finitely generatedness of $M$ or how we concluded that $J(R)M \subseteq M'$. My question is not about explaining the authors' proof. I will understand it in time.
Here's Dennis and Farb's proof:

Proof: Since $J(R)$ annihilates every simple $R$-module, we have $J(R)(M/M') = 0$ for all maximal submodules $M'$ of $M$, and so $J(R)M \subseteq M'$. If $M$ is finitely generated and non-zero, then such an $M'$ exists by Zorn's Lemma, and hence $J(R)M \neq M$ since $M'$ is proper, contradicting the given. Thus $M$ must be zero and we are done.

I found the following proof by contrapositive earlier today, in Appendix A.
Appendix A
(This was originally a proof by contradiction, but I modified it into a proof by contrapositive since that seemed slightly more elegant. It uses a characterization of the Jacobson radical that I was looking at yesterday)
Let $M$ be a non-empty not-necessarily finitely generated $R$-module $M$ such that $J(R)M = M$.
Let $G = \{g_1 \cdots g_n \cdots\}$ be a set of generators of $M$ of minimal size among all sets of elements that generate $M$.
By hypothesis, $-g_1 = \sum r_i g_i$, where cofinitely many $r_i$ are $0$.
Hence $0 = (1+r_1)g_1 + \sum_{i \le 2} r_i g_i$.
Since $r_1$ is in the Jacobson radical, $1+r_1$ is invertible.
Hence $0 = g_1 + \sum_{i \le 2} \frac{r_i}{1+r_1} g_i$
Hence $g_1 = \sum_{i \le 2} \frac{-r_i}{1 + r_1} g_i$.
Since $g_1$ is expressible in terms of the other generators it follows that $G \setminus \{g_1\}$ is also a generating set.
$G$ has minimal size among generating sets by hypothesis, therefore $G$ and $G \setminus \{g_1\}$ have the same size.
Therefore $G$ is infinite, completing the contrapositive argument.

Induction on the number of generators of $E$. Let $x_1,...,x_n$, be generators of E. By hypothesis, there exist elements $a_1$, ..., $a_n$, $in$ $\mathcal a$ such that
$x_s$ $=$ $\mathcal a_1$ $x_1$ $+... +$ $\mathcal a_s$ $x_s$,
so there is an element a (namely $-a_s$) in a such that $(1 + a)x$, lies in the module generated by the first $s - 1$ generators. Furthermore $1 + a$ is a unit in $A$, otherwise $1+a$ is contained in some maximal ideal, and since a lies in all maximal ideals, we conclude that $1$ lies in a maximal ideal, which is not possible. Hence $x$, itself lies in the module generated by $s - 1$ generators, and the proof is complete by induction.
